# Hosting Wordpress with docker on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, docker

I created an Azure deployment using Docker's "wordpress + mysql" template. I need to edit the wp-config.php file, but I can't find it anywhere on the file system. Can someone help point me to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing this file, is that it lives inside the docker container's file system.

Here are the steps you need to do to find this file:

1. SSH into your VM running the Docker containers
2. List all running containers: `docker ps` - get the `CONTAINER ID` of the container with `NAME` 'wordpress'
3. Start a bash inside the wordpress container: `docker exec -i -t 6095ee8642410f77ce8a5f9628b55e23a349e6f744111b2fa9abf1b9fe6b035f bash`
4. Presto - you now have a bash prompt inside your running docker container. Here you can list files with `ls` and find the `wp-config.php` file you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: It should be noted though that the proper way to edit `wp-config.php` is via a `Dockerfile` and not directly in a running container. For testing purposes this is fine of course.